# C++: First non-repeating character, O(n) time using hash map

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, hash, hashmap

I'm trying to write a function to get the first non-repeating character of a string. I haven't found a satisfactory answer on how to do this in O(n) time for all cases. My current solution is:

```
char getFirstNonRepeated(char * str) {
    if (strlen(str) > 0) {
        int visitedArray[256] = {};    // Where 256 is the size of the alphabet
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
            visitedArray[str[i]] += 1;
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < 256; j++) {
            if (visitedArray[j] == 1) return j;
        }

    }
    return '\0';    // Either strlen == 0 or all characters are repeated
}
```

However, as long as n < 256, this algorithm runs in O(n^2) time in the worst case. I've read that using a hash table instead of an array to store the number of times each character is visited could get the algorithm to run consistently in O(n) time, because insertions, deletions, and searches on hash tables run in O(1) time. I haven't found a question that explains how to do this properly. I don't have very much experience using hash maps in C++ so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: OK, O(N^2) comes from `strlen`, but you don't even need that.

Comment: I don't think this even does what you want it to. eg. If i/p is `"dac"`, your o/p should be `d` and not `a` (if I understand correctly) but your code will o/p `a`

Comment: O notation is about asymptotic limits. It is meaningless to say "as long as n < 256, this algorithm runs in O(...)", because if `n` is limited to some constant `k` possibilities, and the algorithm terminates for every value of `n`, then the algorithm runs in `O(1)` *by definition*.  (There is some constant `c` which is the maximum time for any legal value of `n`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why are you repeating those calls to strlen() in every loop? That is linear with the length of the string, so your first loop effectively becomes O(n^2) for no good reason at all. Just calculate the length once and store it, or use str[i] as the end condition.

You should also be aware that if your compiler uses signed characters, any character value above 127 will be considered negative (and used as a negative, i.e. out of bounds, array offset). You can avoid this by explicitly casting your character values to be unsigned char.

Comment: I didn't even think about the strlen() calls. I created a variable to store the length and just used that instead. So would this implementation be considered close enough to O(n)? No way to improve it?

Comment: Well, apart from the strlen() calls, your function is already O(n). It's only the strlen that pushes it to O(n^2).

Comment: Okay. I guess I was just confused a bit then. I thought that if n < 256, then you iterate over the list and then iterate over another list that's as large or larger, so it would have pushed it past O(n). Wasn't sure if that was an issue or if there was a more optimum way of doing it.

Comment: You might be focusing a little too much on O-notation. Officially the first loop (with the strlen removed) is O(n). The second loop, which is not dependent on the length of the input to begin with, is O(1). Together they are O(n). If the second loop had also been O(n), both loops together would still have been O(n).